# Unable to get definition for Sales.vw_CustomerOrders view in AdventureWorks2017 sample database

Tags: sql-server

Looking at the AdventureWorks2017 database I ran across a view called Sales.vw_CustomerOrders. Wondering where it was getting its data I tried to query the object definition and the results came back NULL

```
SELECT definition
FROM   sys.sql_modules
WHERE  object_id = Object_id('Sales.vw_CustomerOrders')
```

I noticed the icon is slightly different from the other views and SSMS won't allow you to generate a create statement either (only a drop). What is this particular view? Why can't you generate a create statement for it? How can I find out how it gets its data?

TIA

Comment: I downloaded a fresh bak file of AdventureWorks2017 but there is no object named Sales.vw_CustomerOrders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MeyssamToluie mentioned in comments, view `Sales.vw_CustomerOrders` is not part of the out-of-box `AdventureWorks` database.

The different SSMS icon indicates the object is encrypted. When a view is created using `WITH ENCRYPION` option, the definition is obfuscated, not visible in the `sys.sql_modules` system view, and the `CREATE` cannot be scripted via normal methods. You'll find undocumented/unsupported ways to get the clear text definition of obfuscated objects with an internet search.

Use `OBJECTPROPERTY` to identify the encryption status of the view:

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsEncrypted') AS IsEncrypted, *
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Sales.vw_CustomerOrders');
```

Comment: That totally makes sense. I see that it is. Thanks for the tip.